# next-auth signin redirects back to /api/auth/signin before the callback is properly fired

Tags: next-auth

EDIT: I found this https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/7785 and after upgrading my Node version from 18 to 20, the problem disappeared.

---

I'm trying to build a simple Next.js app with next-auth. It seems I keep getting redirected from `api/auth/signin` back to the same `api/auth/signin` whenever I try to run any authentication methods. The client makes a POST request to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/credentials, with csrfToken in payload, but gets `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true` with Sign in page HTML as a response (status 302).

I have tried a [T3 app](https://create.t3.gg/), out-of-the-box installation with Discord authentication, and also tried to add e-mail magic link there, just in case something was wrong with Discord.

Then I tried building an app from scratch with the credentials provider, which worked for some time but then all of a sudden started to behave the same way. The code base of that one is here: https://github.com/jarmo-seljamaa/my-app-next-auth.git

I have added console.logs in my `session` and `jwt` callbacks, which were printing out perfectly fine, but when the redirect issue appeared, these callbacks are not being fired and nothing gets printed to terminal.

Another thing I noticed is that the `/api/` request, which should currently send only authenticated: true/false, will output a strange error:

The `/api/route.ts`:

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "./auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
    
    return NextResponse.json({ authenticated: !!session })
}
```

The error:

```
- error TypeError: Response.json is not a function
    at Function.json (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:67:35)
    at GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/route.ts:18:98)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:37)
```

Notice that the code returns `NextResponse.json`, but the error logs a type error on `Response.json`. Is that something?