# next auth login not working with Next.Js 13

Tags: next.js, oauth, google-oauth, next-auth

I've recently created a Next.Js (13.4.19) app and to manage the authnetication system I've used next-auth (4.23.1). I've followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2h54xz6Ndw&t=2054s) and did all the things to setup my auth system using only providers (GitHub and Google).

**The problem occurs when I try to login: the app sends me to the correct signin route (api/auth/signin)** and when I click on the buttons nothing happens; the page refreshes itself, but no errors in the console.

Here's my code:

`app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import { options } from '@/app/utils/options';

const handler = NextAuth(options);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

`app/utils/options.ts`

```js
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import { validateCredentials } from './helpers/getCredentials';

import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord';

const googleCredentials = validateCredentials(
  process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
  process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!
);

const githubCredentials = validateCredentials(
  process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID!,
  process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET!
);

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: googleCredentials.clientId,
      clientSecret: googleCredentials.clientSecret,
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: githubCredentials.clientId,
      clientSecret: githubCredentials.clientSecret,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Here are the settings of the GitHub OAuth app I've created
[image]

I've tried watching other possible solutions on youtube and github, but nothing works. Every time I try to login nothing happens. For example, if I click on the GitHub button, it should redirect me to the github login page; instead, the current page refreshes and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/7785 and after upgrading my Node version from 18 to 20, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Upgrading node version to 20 worked for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing a similar issue (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76919999/next-auth-signin-redirects-back-to-api-auth-signin-before-the-callback-is-prope)) but have not found any info on how to fix that.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77021542/14038113) might also a similar case.