# NextAuth.js signIn response always undefined

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-auth

Whenever I run my `authorize` callback in NextAuth from my `signIn` function in my page, the result is undefined regardless of what I do. The page also refreshes immediately with the `callbackUrl` query.

- I am using the [Credentials Provider](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials) from NextAuth.
- I am using the [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) from NextJs

**This is my auth route:**

```js
// app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'username', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' }
      },
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async authorize(credentials) {
      // const { username, password } = credentials;

      // mocking API request (doesn't work, just refreshes immediately)
      await delay(3000);

      try {
        
        return { user: "Shiawase" };

      } catch (error) {

        throw new Error('Failed to authenticate user');
      }
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/login' 
  }
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**And this is my login logic within my page:**

```
  // app/auth/login/page.tsx
  async function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const result = await signIn('Credentials', {
        username: data.username,
        password: data.password,
        redirect: false
    });
    // result is undefined
    console.log(result)
    if (result) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.log("Successfully logged in")
        setTimeout(() => {
            router.push('/user/dashboard/home');
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log("Something unexpected occurred");
        return;
    }
}
```

- My NextJs version is `14.1.0`
- My Node.Js version is `20.12.0`

**I have tried:**

- Upgrading my Node Version [[Here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77027818/next-auth-login-not-working-with-next-js-13/77141293#77141293)

Comment: have you wrapped your app with next auth's provider?

Answer (score 0):

On the app router, you should use version 5 of `next auth` which is currently in beta. I will show you step-by-step to how migrate your code to V5.

###### Step 1: Update next-auth dependency

```bash
npm install next-auth@5.0.0-beta.16
```

###### Step 2: Change the code in the `route.js` file

###### util/auth.js

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

export const authConfig = {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'username', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        // const { username, password } = credentials;

        // mocking API request (doesn't work, just refreshes immediately)
        await delay(3000);

        try {
         
          return { user: "Shiawase" };

        } catch (error) {

          throw new Error('Failed to authenticate user');
        }
      },
    })
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/login' 
  }
}

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth(authConfig);
```

###### app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```js
export { GET, POST } from "../../../../util/auth.js";
```

###### Step 3: SignIn the user

Keep in mind that the `signIn`, `signOut` and `auth` functions should run on the server side and NOT in client. You can put `signIn` and `signOut` in the server actions to use them:

```js
import { auth, signIn } from "util/auth.js"

export const MyServerComponent = async () => {
    const session = await auth();

    if(session) {
        redirect("/");
    }
 
    return (
        <div>
            <button 
                formAction={async () => {
                    "use server";

                    await signIn("Credentials");
                }}
            >
                Sign In
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello, I followed these changes and now my `signIn` function returns this url: `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin` with the callback query aswell,same  issue is persisting though.

Comment: @Shiawase I checked the code again and realized that you used `authorized` function in a wrong object. it should be inside `Credentials` not `callback`. I edited the code in the answer